# How to download a file from php page using phonegap (Android platform)?

Tags: php, android, cordova

I'm using phonegap to create an Android application ,in this app I'd like to allow the user to download a file from a php page (server side) ,that's where I'm having troubles . Here is the html page index.html from my Android project :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Download</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="down" name="down" action="http://172.25.10.99/test/download.php" method="GET">
    <!-- 172.25.10.99 : server IP -->
        <input type="text" name="filename" id="filename"/>
        <input type="submit" id="id2" value="download"/> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the php page download.php :

```
        <?php

    try {
        $file = "D:\\file\\" . $_REQUEST['filename'];
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $file = "D:\\file\\pdf2.pdf";
    }
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($file));
    fclose($fp);
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header("Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file));
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");

?>
```

The problem is : I'm getting nothing when I press the download button in my application (after inserting a file name which is correct and exists on the server), while I'm expecting to see a download window that asks me where to save the requested file ,or better than that ,to find the requested file in the download folder downloaded automatically ,and I believe that the problem is somewhere in the header in the php page.Could you please help ? I'd really appreciate it ..

Comment: Do you have idea about Download file Plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FileTransfer.download`, here is an example:

```
function downloadFile(){

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
        "dummy.html", {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.html","");
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            fileEntry.remove();

            fileTransfer.download(
                "http://www.w3.org/2011/web-apps-ws/papers/Nitobi.pdf",
                sPath + "theFile.pdf",
                function(theFile) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                    showLink(theFile.toURI());
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
                }
            );
        }, fail);
    }, fail);
};
```

}

Comment: I believe this will work if the requested file is reachable without the php page in my question ,but as you can see the file exists in local disk of the server's computer Not in the www folder (in case the server is using wamp program) and My question was how to download the file with the existence of the php page ,Any other ideas please ??

Comment: looks like it works ! just by adding the parameters to the url which is my php page url ,the parameters are the file name I want to download.

Comment: @Amit Prajapati: Where does this download to? Path?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is close to the answer above but is simpler and easier to understand ,although I must say I wouldn't come to this answer without Mr. Amit help ,here is my solution :

```
<script>
        function downloadFile2()
        {       
        alert("I'm in df2");     
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI("http://172.25.10.170/test/download.php?select=img.jpg");
        var filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/img.jpg";
        fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            filePath,
            function(entry) {
                document.getElementById("id11").innerHTML="download complete: " + entry.fullPath;
            },
            function(error) {
                document.getElementById("id11").innerHTML="download error source " + error.source;
                document.getElementById("id11").innerHTML="download error target " + error.target;
                document.getElementById("id11").innerHTML="upload error code" + error.code;
            },
            true,
            {
            }
        );
        };
</script>
        <button id="downtbtn2" onClick="downloadFile2();" >downloadTest</button>
        <br/>
        <label id="id11">here should be the result</label>
```